# R squared for random effects model after multiple imputation with mice

Tags: r, imputation, r-mice, random-effects

I'm having difficulties with calculating **r squared** (ideally **between** and overall r squared, but between is more important to me) for a random effects model after multiple imputation with mice. The function `pool.r.squared()` only works for lm objects. I have tried for quite a while now, but I cannot figure out how to do it. This is my code:

```
imp <- mice(data_panel, 
               m=5,
               maxit=5)
fit.1 <- with(imp,
              plm(y ~ x1 + x2 + x3 + x4,
              data = data.frame(mget(ls())),
              index = c("Name", "Year"),
              model = "random")) 

summary(pool(fit.1))
```

I tried to make use of this post: [Adjusted R squared using 'mice'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62702164/adjusted-r-squared-using-mice) but I couldn't get it work for a plm model. Any help would be greatly appreciated.